# Handling a complex JSON response with ArrayList inside another ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress, arraylist

Ok! I have a really complex JSON which I parsed using Retrofit library, via an Asynchronous Process.

Actually I am parsing the Wordpress JSON, using the JSON API. And I am displaying all the posts title and content in a recyclerview adapter.

Getting new posts title and content was very easy though. I am facing problem at creating the ModelClass for it. The following is the JSON format:

```
    {
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 10,
  "count_total": 26,
  "pages": 3,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 274,
      "title": "A ver, very long post!",
      "content":"BLAH BLAH",
      "excerpt":"BLAH",
    "attachments": [
        {
          "id": 201,
          "url": "http://example.com/image.jpg",
          "slug": "iamge.jpg",
          "title": "iamge.jpg",
          "description": "",
          "caption": "",
          "parent": 274,
          "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
          "images": {
            "full": {
              "url": "http://example.com/image.jpg",
              "width": 480,
              "height": 480
            },
            "thumbnail": {
              "url": "http://example.com/image.jpg",
              "width": 150,
              "height": 150
            },
            "medium": {
              "url": "http://example.com/image.jpg",
              "width": 300,
              "height": 300
            },
            "medium_large": {
              "url": "http://example.com/image.jpg",
              "width": 480,
              "height": 480
            },
            "large": {
              "url": "http://example.com/image.jpg",
              "width": 480,
              "height": 480
            }
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

My model class contains the following class variables alongwith the getter methods:

```
private int id;
    private String type;
    private String slug;
    private String url;
    private String status;
    private String title;
    private String title_plain;
    private String content;
    private String excerpt;
    private String date;
    private String modified;
    private String[] categories;
    private String[] tags;
    private String author;
    private String[] comments;
    public ArrayList<AttachmentClass> attachments = new ArrayList<AttachmentClass>();
```

My problem is with the ArrayList attachments. Attachments are a collection of string type data and other user-defined class variables....

I am able to get the posts, title etc.. But I can't figure out how to get data from the ArrayList of various attachments... Please help...

In the adapter class, I am using

```
private ArrayList<ModelClass> dataset;
String message = dataset.get(getLayoutPosition()).getContent();
String title = dataset.get(getLayoutPosition()).getTitle();
```

These calls give me results.... I just don't know how to display the data from the Array List (Attachments) from the data set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say attachments have an array of objects.
Your AttachmentClass should include all fields: id,url, slug... and class of images which include fields: full, thumbnail, medium etc...

Note 'images' in your case is not an array of objects, its just a single object

And use for() cycle to get all items from attachments
like this:
for(i)
dataset.get(getLayoutPosition()).getAttachements(i).getImage().getFull()

Hope i helped you :)

Comment: But, getAttachments() is an ArrayList, I can't use the getImage()  on it...

Comment: Maybe like this for(int i =0; i < dataset.get(getLayoutPosition()).getAttachements().size(); i++ ) { ... dataset.get(getLayoutPosition()).getAttachements().get(i).getImage();}

Comment: Oh! Thank you! That worked like magic! I've been searching all around for a fix... Man you're like an Angel! Thanks a ton...